# How to neglect "Invalid column name" error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created some SQL statements for some migration:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableA' AND COLUMN_NAME='Status')
BEGIN
  UPDATE TableA 
  SET Status = 'Active' 
  WHERE Status IS NULL
END
```

Now, I have dropped the column `Status` from database table `TableA`.

Again when I am executing the above block, and although I have placed a check whether that column exists, only then it should execute the `UPDATE` statement, it gives me error

> Invalid column name 'Status'

How to get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: Also I request you to suggest me some suitable title for this question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the code to run in a separate scope/batch:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableA' AND COLUMN_NAME='Status')
BEGIN

  EXEC('UPDATE TableA SET Status=''Active'' WHERE Status IS NULL')

END
```

The problem you currently have is that the system wants to *compile* your batch of code before it executes any part of it. It can't *compile* the `UPDATE` statement since there's a column missing, so it never even has a chance to start *executing* the code and considering whether the `EXISTS` predicate returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Your current SQL Block might fail some times because Information_schema is view and not a table. Also, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

**`Some changes have been made to the information schema views that break backward compatibility.`**

Hence we can't rely on **information schema views**.

Instead use **sys.tables**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.COLUMNS
              WHERE NAME = N'Status' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'TableA'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableA SET Status='Active' WHERE Status IS NULL
END
```

Comment: The question is I want SQL Server to avoid the column name "Status" whether it is exists or not. I have placed a check that If exists column then only it should execute the block. Right now the column "Status" is not exists so that "UPDATE" statement is not going to be executed. Still I am getting the error "Invalid column name".